# How to connect two nodes via WLAN interface in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have three nodes in the network `NodeA`, `NodeB` and `NodeC` which are all `WirelessHost`. I have to connect `NodeA` and `NodeB` through `ppp` interface and also connect `NodeB` and `NodeC` through `WLAN` Interface. I have connected `NodeA` and `NodeB` as:

```
NodeA.pppg++ <--> Channel <--> NodeB.pppg++;
```

Now I want to connect `NodeB` and `NodeC` as well through `WLAN` but I am not sure how to do this. Can someone please suggest me how to do this in `OMNeT++` or `INET` framework?

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you intend to connect to two wireless nodes.

- In *infrastructure mode* you would need an additional AccessPoint,
- In *AdHoc mode* you should reconfigure the node's wireless interfaces to run in adhoc mode.

You can find examples in: `inet/examples/wireless/`

especially `inet/examples/wireless/wiredandwirelesshostswithap` does something similar (a bit more complicated) that you need.